# JQGrid loadui block not working

Tags: jqgrid

I would like to disable actions on JQGrid like clicking on checkbox, scrolling down the page when ajax operation is going on. I have tried to use **loadui: 'block'** in JQGrid but is not working. Any other set of code that needs to be added ?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear to me. But, if you want to block screen when you call an ajax function, you can do it on `beforeSend` and unblock it on `complete` :

```
$.ajax({
    //type, url, etc.
    beforeSend: function(){
        $.blockUI.defaults.applyPlatformOpacityRules = false;
        $.blockUI({ 
            message : "Loading...",
            centerY: 0, 
            baseZ: 2000,
            css: { top: '0px', left: '', right: '512px' } 
        }); 
    },
    complete: function(xmldata, stat){
        $.unblockUI();
    }                  
});
```

But, if you're trying to make it on add/edit/delete event of jqGrid, you should block on `onclickSubmit: function(params, postdata) { //block screen }` and unblock it on `afterSubmit: function(response, postData) { //unblock screen }`. You can find more info about jqGrid events at [this link](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing) and [this one](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:events)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply. Couldn't make it work though.

Solved with below piece of code.

```
    loadBeforeSend: function(){
        var $gbox = $("#list").closest('.ui-jqgrid');
        $gbox.block({
            message: "<h1>Loading...</h1>",
            css: { border: "3px solid #a00" }
        });
    },
    loadComplete: function(data) {
         var $gbox = $("#list").closest('.ui-jqgrid');
         $gbox.unblock();
    },
```